# Prove if $R$ is not a field then the value set $δ(R)$ is infinite, $δ$ a Euclidean degree function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, euclidean-domain

I was trying to solve this exercise in my course notes, but the statement didn't seem right to me. When looking at the ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, it is clearly not a field since $2 + \mathbb{Z}$ does not have an inverse. But the set $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ , which is $\{0+ \mathbb{Z};1+ \mathbb{Z};2+ \mathbb{Z};3+ \mathbb{Z}\}$ is finite, and we could easily define a Euclidean degree function on it with a finite value set ( by letting $δ(1) = δ(3) = 1$ , $δ(2) = 2$ and $δ(0) = -\infty$).

So this is a ring that is not a field with a Euclidean degree function on it with a finite value set. I'm I wrong or does the ring have to be infinite or none of the previous ?

Also would the contraposition of the statement be : $δ(R)$ finite $\Rightarrow$ $R$ a field ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should say more about the restrictions on the ring and the exact properties of $\delta.$  If a Euclidean domain is meant,...

Comment: @WillJagy The only thing given in the exercise is $δ$ a euclidean degree function of a ring $R$ so I assume $R$ is a euclidean domain. Is that what you mean with restrictions on the ring ?

Comment: And is my statement valid with regards to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Moee If it's a Euclidean domain, then your statement is not valid, because it is not a domain.

Comment: @MattSamuel Exactly because 2*2 gives 0..

Comment: @Moeee Which disqualifies $\mathbb Z_4$ from being a Euclidean domain.

Comment: But is the statement in the title true ? And if so how could I try to prove it ?

Comment: My original answer assumed $\delta(-1)=0$, which need not be the case. This is where we need to use the assumption that $x$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that $\delta(a)\leq \delta(ab)$ for all $a,b\neq 0$. Using this, we show that if $\delta(x)>0$ and $x$ is not a unit then $\delta(x)<\delta(x^2)$.

Let $\delta(x)>0$ for some $x$ that is not a unit. Then there exist $q$ and $r$ such that
$$x^3 + x = qx^2+r$$
with $\delta(r)<\delta(x^2)$. Thus
$$x(x^2+1) = qx^2+r$$
$$x(x^2+1-qx) = r$$
If $r=0$, then $qx=x^2+1$, so
$$x(x-q)=-1$$
which is a contradiction since in such a situation $x$ has an inverse (namely $q-x$). Thus $r\neq 0$, $\delta(r)<\delta(x^2)$, and $\delta(r)\geq \delta(x)$ since $\delta(x(x^2+1-qx))\geq \delta(x)$. It follows that $\delta(x)<\delta(x^2)$.

We can thus recursively construct an increasing sequence of values $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ such that $x_0=x$ and
$$x_i=x_{i-1}^2$$
By the same argument, $\delta(x_{i-1})<\delta(x_i)$ for all $i$, hence the number of values is infinite.

Comment: Perhaps make it clear that [we may assume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition) that $\delta(a) \le \delta (ab)$ for all nonzero $a,b \in R$.